# File level Git remotes

Tags: git, github

I wonder if there's a solution to what I want to achieve.

There is a base framework Git repository that contains the base code that is used across multiple websites.

Each website also has its own repository that only contains config and custom code for that website.

In order for the website to run, the two codebases are merged together (via `rsync`, or `cp`) and create (build) each website.

While developers work on the website, there'll be working with the merged code. However when file changes are committed, if a file from the base framework is committed and pushed it should be pushed to the base framework.

Similarly, if the file was a config / custom change that belonged to a website it should push to the website's repository.

Is this even possible, there's tracking needed to track which file belonged to which repository.

- Is there a solution out there
- Is this a good pattern to follow
- Any suggestions or alternative if its not a viable solution.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using submodules, but this seems rather vague.